# Linux 20.04 to MobaXterm Connection Refused Problem

Tags: networking, ssh

I am trying to connect Ubuntu Linux 20.04 to MobaXterm with SSH. I tried everything but MobaXterm gives error as "Network error: Connection refused"

I have just started to learn Linux, I am taking a lot of problem but I didn't handle this one.

What is the problem on my Linux?

Thanks in advance.

**SSH**

```
ssh 127.0.0.1
```

**Reply**

```
 Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-56-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 updates can be applied immediately.

New release '22.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2025.
Last login: Fri Dec 23 23:12:49 2022 from 127.0.0.1
```

- I didn't see any problem here.

**LISTEN**

```
sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep LISTEN
```

**Reply**

```
systemd-r  491 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  19124      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
cupsd      568            root    6u  IPv6  22865      0t0  TCP [::1]:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd      568            root    7u  IPv4  22866      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:631 (LISTEN)
sshd       687            root    3u  IPv4  25177      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       687            root    4u  IPv6  25179      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
```

**Ssh Status**

```
systemctl status sshd
```

**Reply**

```
* ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-12-23 23:18:05 +03; 17min ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 674 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 687 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18658)
     Memory: 7.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             `-687 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups

Warning: some journal files were not opened due to insufficient permissions.
```

**Local Ports**

```
ss -plnt
State              Recv-Q             Send-Q                         Local Address:Port                           Peer Address:Port             Process             
LISTEN             0                  4096                           127.0.0.53%lo:53                                  0.0.0.0:*                                    
LISTEN             0                  128                                  0.0.0.0:22                                  0.0.0.0:*                                    
LISTEN             0                  5                                  127.0.0.1:631                                 0.0.0.0:*                                    
LISTEN             0                  128                                     [::]:22                                     [::]:*                                    
LISTEN             0                  5                                      [::1]:631                                    [::]:*
```

**UNF STATUS**

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
2222/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
2222/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

**PING**

```
ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.039 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
```

**MobaXterm Connection Problem**

[image: MobaXterm Connection Problem]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Your question is very hard to follow since you have shown that everything on your Ubuntu install is working fine.  I would suggest cleaning up your question and actually showing how you are not able to connect to MobaXterm or that MobaXterm cannot connect to 127.0.0.1.  Thank you!

Comment: If you edit your host or mouse over it in MobaXterm it shows Host: 127.0.0.1, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by editing my WSL session in MobaXterm and changing the "Run method" from "Localhost connection" to "Autodetection".